# How to get all the articles by only knowing half of the ID or Name?

Tags: php, templates, articles, mysql

I need to get an array of all the articles that have a fixed part in their ID or Name and then create a template based of them.
For example:

I'll create many articles that have in their ID "plants" ,the ID's will be (plants_1,plants_2......) and I need to get all of them and then put them in a couple of div's and everytime a new article is created it will appear on the website.

How can I do that ?
I know some php and sql but not much.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all your articles in a Category and create "Category Blog/List" menu item to show them. Any article you add into this category will be shown when you click on the menu item you created.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you!